# Get data from one textbox on form1 from another textbox on form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two forms form1 and form2. I want to get the text from the textbox of form2 when a button is clicked on form1. I am using on form1:

```
private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 f2=new Form2();
    txtonform1=f2.fo;
}
```

and on `form2` I have this method to return the text from the textbox:

```
public string fo
{            
    get { return textBox1.Text; }
    set { textBox1.Text = value; }
}
```

Now the problem is that it returns `null`. Whats the problem I am new to c# can anybody help me please!

Comment: is `form2` already displayed or you want to display it and then continue...

Answer (score 1):

You have to work with one single form, otherwise you create new instance every time:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();

private void but1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f2.fo=txtonform1.Text;
}

private void but2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(f2.fo);
}
```

Comment: this is not a solution i think?

Comment: @user3115728 did you try it?

Comment: @user3115728 so please post more code... where exactly you get null?

Comment: i simple need the text from the Form2's textbox in the Form1

Comment: f2.fo=txtonform1.Text;
here i get nothing

Comment: @user3115728 of course you get nothing, `txtonform1` is on Form1.

Comment: @user3115728 you need to show the form first e.g. `f2.ShowModal()` before reading its textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new form instance here:

```
 Form2 f2=new Form2();
```

And your `fo` property return this new form's `textBox1`, so you textBox1 doesn't contain any text and you are getting null.

I guess you are displaying form2 from Form1, if it's correct just define a one Form2 intance in class level:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   Form2 f2 = new Form2();
}
```

And when you want to show it use this:

```
f2.Show(this);
```

When you want to change your TextBox value now you can use:

```
txtonform1.Text = f2.fo;
```

But to do this make sure you change your textBox1.Text in form2.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the reference of `form2` which is/was already displayed, in `form1` and then use the same variable to access the value.

I don't know how `form2` was created and shown but assuming it's created and shown by some button click on `form1` then `form1` class will look something like,

```
private Form f2 = null;   

private void buttonShowForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(f2 == null)
        f2 = new form2();
    f2.Show();
}

private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(f2 == null)  //If this form was not already displayed display it to get the input from user
       buttonShowForm2_Click(null, null);
    else
       txtonform1=f2.fo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**FIRST  SOLUTION:**

> 1.) Goto Form2 then Double click it. At the code type this.

```
public Form2(string sTEXT)
{
InitializeComponent();
textBox1.Text = sTEXT;
}

2.) Goto Form1 then Double click it. At the code type this.
//At your command button in Form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form2 sForm = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
sForm.Show();
}
```

**SECOND SOLUTION:**

> 1.) Goto Form1 then Double Click it. At the code type this.

```
public string CaptionText
{
get {return textBox1.Text;}
set { textBox1.Text = value;}
}
```

note: the value of your textbox1.text = sayre;

2.) Goto Form2 then Double click it. At the code type this.

```
// At your command button In Form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Form1 sForm1 = new Form1();
textBox1.Text = sForm1.CaptionText;
}
```